# JPA: Reuse persistence.xml with jta-data-source in JSE and JUnit by overriding the datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have this `peristence.xml` that deploys on WildFly:

```
  <persistence-unit name="optaweb-employee-rostering-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
```

Now I'd like to reuse it in a plain Java application, with a direct JDBC connection, so *without JNDI*:

```
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "sa");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");

    // Overwrites transaction-type successfully 
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "RESOURCE_LOCAL");

    // TODO overwrite jta-data-source

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "optaweb-employee-rostering-persistence-unit", properties);
```

**How do I overwrite `jta-data-source`?**

---

I've tried a number of JPA properties to override `jta-data-source`, with no success:

```
    // Overwrites jta-data-source
    // but triggers a JNDI lookup of "" which crashes of course
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", "");
    // Does not overwrite jta-data-source
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", null);

    // Does not overwrite jta-data-source
    properties.put("javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource", "foo");
```

I've also tried a number of hibernate specific properties, such as `hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class` and `hibernate.connection.datasource` with the same failing results as above.

Comment: [Related jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12858)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the source of Hibernate ORM (in particular `org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl#EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.PersistenceUnitDescriptor, java.util.Map, java.lang.ClassLoader, org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService)`), these particular JPA settings override settings from `hibernate.properties` or from the Map you will provide to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`.

It may be a dumb idea, but can't you just do the opposite, i.e. not set the datasource in your persistence unit, but set it through a `hibernate.properties` file in your WildFly application? Then you can do whatever you want in your plain java application.